# Strange postgres slow query every day around the same time on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a production app on heroku with postgres, serving a Rails API. Every day between 7-8am, there will be one or more long-running requests (about 20s or more) and it only occurs then. According to logs the time spent is in the database

- There are no scheduled jobs
- Backups are not scheduled anywhere close to that time
- Traffic is at its lowest at that time
- Memory is stable
- There are other requests between the daily restart and that, so the dynos are not "cold"
- It is not always the same endpoint, and it doesn't occur any other time

I'm not sure if it means anything but timezone is Singapore GMT+8, so 7-8am is right before midnight.

Has anyone else experienced this or has ideas to troubleshoot?

**EDIT to add details:**

[image]

You can see here (Scout APM) that it precedes the high throughput, basically before the start of the work day, so it's not due to load.

[image]

In fact there is pretty much no load at all. Neither is it the first request since server restart (at 4am). The slow request at 7:46am here was repeated at night (same url, same query string) which finished in under a second

Comment: Use `auto_explain` to catch the execution plans of long running statements. If you can afford the performance hit, set `auto_explain.analyze` and `auto_explain.buffers` to `on`.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe but it's not an issue of a slow / unoptimised query. If I run the exact query at another time it'll only be 100 ms or so. It just happens that one or more queries at that particular time of day will run up to 20s. Will `auto_explain` still show anything useful?

Comment: If you have the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output auto_explain can generate, you would know much more. Particularly if `track_io_timing = on`. Another thing you can check is the kernel log.

Comment: What class of heroku instance is this?

Comment: @jjanes hobby (not free) dynos and hobby-basic postgres – basically the first tier of paid plans for each. I added more details and some APM screenshots in the post, thanks

Comment: I am having an identical problem - everyday, exactly at 2am, queries slow down, but there are 10x faster literally at any other point during the day. @PeterWong have you had any luck?

Comment: @MaximFedotov I contacted support – they tried to help after i repeated multiple times that it is not an unoptimised query. Ultimately they could not say anything useful, and I suggested if it's possible that the shared nature of postgres could affect this. They said it might, and said I could try forking/migrating the database to a new instance (and thus another pool of users). I have not tried this as the problem has become more sporadic recently. Let me know if you try it

Comment: I would start to look for other tasks that are started at that time. They can be even on another machine, it is enough if they grab a resource that the DB also needs, like network bandwidth, some disk device etc. A backup program might be the culprit, (but you ruled them out, already...)